# Maxima/Minima given a constraint

Tags: maxima-minima

Let $f$ and $g$ be functions on $R^2$ deﬁned respectively by
$$f(x,y)=\frac{1}{3}x^3+\frac{3}{2}y^2+2x$$
and
$$g(x,y)=x−y$$
Consider the problems of maximizing and minimizing $f$ on the constraint set $$C=\{{(x,y)∈R^2:g(x,y)=0\}}$$
(a) $f$ has a maximum at $(x=1,y=1)$ , and a minimum at $(x=2,y=2)$.

(b) $f$ has a maximum at $(x=1,y=1)$ , but does not have a minimum.

(c) $f$ has a minimum at $(x=2,y=2)$ , but does not have a maximum.

(d) $f$ has neither a maximum nor a minimum.

## My approach

I figured the constraint set is the set of all $x=y$ replaced this in $f$ and differentiated to obtain a maxima at $(x=1,y=1)$ and a minima at $(x=2,y=2)$. The answer however states there is no maximum or minimum. Where am I at fault? Does it have something to do with the order of growth of $x^3$ ?

Comment: That is indeed what i did but the my answer disagrees with the solution.

Comment: If $x - y = 0 \implies y=x$, so we have to find the extrema of $\dfrac{1}{3}x^3+\dfrac{3}{2}x^2+2x$. Since there is no constraint on $x$, what is the min and max of this function? Clear? We get no global min or max, but we do have a local min and a local max. Those local min max are located at $(x, y) = (-1, -1)$ for min and $(-2,-2)$ for max.

Comment: Yes you are right and that is why i cannot understand how the answer is d) $f$ has neither a maximum or a minimum.

Comment: Because we are looking for global versus local extrema. There are no global extrema with the contraint. As $x$ gets smaller, we go to negative infinity and as it gets larger, we go to positive infinity. The problem is asking for **global** extrema, not **local** - that is why.

Comment: Right thanks...

Answer (score 0):

There exist local maxima and minima points, where the derivative vanishes. It is easy to see thta such points occur at $(-2,-2)$ and $(-1,-1)$. However, the function dosent have a lower/upper bound. Clearly, fom the constraint equation, since $x=y$,

$f(x,x) = \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{3x^2}{2} + 2x$

clearly as $x \to +\infty$, $f(x,x) \to +\infty$ and as $x\to -\infty, f(x,x) \to -\infty$. Thus, the function has no global maxima or minima(which is what the option mramt i guess).